# Why doesn't sdk version check work?

Tags: android, sdk, android-api-levels

I have this code snippet:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

            if (currentapiVersion < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
                ComponentName cName = new ComponentName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.Settings");
                intent.setComponent(cName);

            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Why doesn't this work on my android phone (api level 15) , but when I replace it with the code below, it works fine?

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
                ComponentName cName = new ComponentName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.Settings");
                intent.setComponent(cName);
```

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't this work" means. Also note that you are only calling `startActivity()` in your `else` block, not the `if` block.

Comment: Oh my god !! Thank you... It was so obvious I couldn't see it ....

Answer (score 0):

> if (currentapiVersion < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
>
> ```
>             Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
>
>             ComponentName cName = new ComponentName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.Settings");
>
>             intent.setComponent(cName); 
>
>             context.startActivity(intent);
>
>
>         } else {
>
>             Intent intent = new Intent();
>
>             intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
>
>          intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
>             context.startActivity(intent);
>         }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

u didnt call startActivity in if Block that is why issue is occuring